# No Module named PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I know PIL is deprecated, so I installed Pillow instead, and for backward compatibility reason, Pillow is still using PIL as its module name.
Here's my *pip freeze* look like for Pillow:
***Pillow=3.2.0***

Here's how I use it in my code:

```
import  PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
```

As someone suggested in a similar post, also, I tried

```
import  PIL 
from PIL import Image
```

Neither works.
Both give me this error:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Also, I tried:

```
import Image
```

it gives me:

```
ImportError: No module named Image
```

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` and `pip --version`?

Comment: @CoryShay Python 2.7.11 and pip 1.5.6, and for various reason, I cannot upgrade both.

Comment: does import Image work?

Comment: @haifzhan nope, I also tried that. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @SSun How about `import pil`?

Comment: @CoryShay still no luck, returns me: No module named pil

Comment: @SSun - seriously, pip 1.5.6? Python 2.7.11 is not old at all, but pip is on 8.1.2, so I think it's completely related to pip and the way it's installing the packages (this affects loading the modules). Do `pip install --upgrade pip` if you have the rights to do so, it will make pip update itself.

Comment: @Signus I just did that and my pip is now 8.1.2, still getting the import error. Also, I don't think it's a good idea for me to upgrade it, it might break my other modules. I'll revert. Thanks though.

Comment: @SSun what is the output of `pip show --files Pillow`? Mainly the location and also the folder for `PIL`. Example (on mine): `Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, `PIL/`. If you are on a *nix based system you should be able to do `pip show --files Pillow | egrep -i "location|pil/"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm on a Windows machine, and I tried pip show --files Pillow, it returns a blank line.

Comment: @SSun I would almost agree at this point with @Signus that it could be your pip version that may be causing the issue. As I installed `pip==1.5.6` on a VM and was successfully able to run `pip show --files Pillow` with `Version: 3.2.0
Location: c:\python27\lib\site-packages`. I would check to make sure that `PIL` is located within `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages` unless Python was installed in a non-default location which it should be `<python dir>\lib\site-packages\PIL`

Comment: I've upgraded my pip to the latest and didn't roll back actually, it's now: pip 8.1.2 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages <python 2.7>, and I ran pip show --files Pillow again, it's displaying all PIL files now.

Comment: Then it works now!! Cool! Thanks a lot. The final import line that's working is: `from PIL import Image`          Thanks a bunch folks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per my comment since it helped you out and answered your problem:

The issue that you were seeing is that you had pip version 1.5.6, and the version of pip does dictate how packages are unzipped, which ultimately determines whether or not modules are loaded properly.

All that is needed is:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Which allows pip to upgrade itself.

Use `sudo` if you're on Mac/Linux, otherwise you'll likely need to 'Run as Administrator' on Windows.

And voila, you can now properly import the PIL modules:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:16:51)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PIL
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image
<module 'PIL.Image' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>
```

Comment: So I followed all your guys comments in the questions, but I am still having issue. It is not finding PIL.

Comment: pip version is at 9.0.1 and python is at 2.7.6; Pillow version is at 4.0.0

Comment: It won't work for virtual env. So I would consider @Arthur's answer instead.

Answer (score 35):

In my case, on Windows, all I needed to do is to run:

`pip install pillow`

Comment: also works for me on mac, in a python virtual environment

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When I run this, I got: **Requirement already satisfied** .

Comment: @botkop that also worked for me in a python enviroment

Comment: I fixed mine by using `pip uninstall pillow` and then `pip install pillow`

Answer (score 6):

You can use `python -m pip install Pillow` or `pip install Pillow`

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this trouble too recently, so let me share my take on this. I'm on Mac OS X Mojave 10.14. I tried running the `pip install pillow` so many times blindly without finding deeper understanding as to where my `python` searches for its packages.

I encountered this error when I upgraded from OS X High Sierra to Mojave. My previously working Scrapy project just stopped running properly.

Note that I didn't use `virtualenv`.

First, you need to check which python is used by the system. In the Terminal, run

```
which -a python
```

You'll get something similar to this:

`nicholass-mbp:~ nicholaslie$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python`

This leads me to searching inside the `/usr/local/` folder. Turns out there's a folder to where my `python` is searching its packages, and that is inside `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` (`python`) or `/usr/local/lib/python3.7` (`python3`)

What my current `pip install pillow` do is installing the `PIL` package inside the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory, but not to `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`

[image: PIL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages]

However, since my project uses Python 3, `No module named PIL` error simply tells you that the `python3` instance you're using cannot find the `PIL` library.

I used Homebrew for managing my system packages such as `node`, `python`, etc. So what I did was reinstall `python3` with Homebrew with:

`brew reinstall python`, then run `pip3 install pillow`.

Just ensure that the `PIL` package is installed properly in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and you should be good to go. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had a similar issue but in reverse. I installed Python 3.7 and Pillow...But had to install Python 2.7 to run some legacy scripts and Pillow was not found. I simply reinstalled Pillow again after switching Python versions.

Answer (score 1):

OSX

```
sudo easy_install pip
pip install Pillow --user
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For me, when I was trying to use PIL in PyCharm, initially the Project Interpreter was not looking at the correct location for Python 3.7. This has been corrected and using PIL works for me now (corrected Interpreter shown in image attached).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for pip version 20 and using PyCharm.
I'd upgrade pip to version 20.0.2 as pip suggested but I had to get back to version 19

```
python -m pip install pip==19.3.1
```

I also installed Pillow from command line

```
pip install Pillow
```

And finally installed Pillow inside PyCharm on Settings -> Project:your-project-name -> Project Interpreter, clicked on + button and installed Pillow.

[image: Pillow installed from inside MyCharm]

Answer (score 0):

For Windosws 11
Fixed mine by using

```
pip uninstall pillow
```

and then

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue with

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

in a virtual environment created with `python3 -m venv .venv` and executing a script with VS Code (which pointed to the interpreter in the virtual environment). None of the above solutions worked for me. Importing the module outside of the virtual environment worked though, without any issues.

After further delving it turned out that `pip install pillow` was not installing the `pillow` module to the virtual environment, because I had `pillow` already installed on the main system interpreter.

The work around to this is to change the value of `include-system-site-packages` to `true` in the `.venv/pyvenv.cfg` file. Then `pillow` is imported without any issues when using the virtual environment interpreter and having `pillow` installed on the main system interpreter.